# NGINX: how to manage different visibility (LAN vs Internet)

Tags: nginx

i've setup a rasberry server with open media vault on board, so i'm using docker to setup multiple services such as:

- pihole
- plex
- nextcloud
  and much more

i would like to expose some of them on internet, while others only on LAN.
For internet i will use SSL from letsencrypt, while for LAN i can use a self-signed certificate.

Right now, i'm thinking to create multiple domains on two ports, one dedicated for internet and the other for lan, but... are there better alternatives (also from a security standpoint) ?

P.S.: right now i'm not considering VPN as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

for the people who will read this, i solved in this way using only a nginx instance (on linuxserver swag image).

1. Created another server block (ports 8443)
2. Created a self signed certificate for the new server block
3. Opened on the router and port forwarded on 443 in order to expose only what i want to expose publicly using proxy-conf
4. Did the same for server block 8443 which is not exposed, so no port forwarding